# Can we use feign client with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

We have a couple of microservices managed using AWS API Gateway which also acts as a load balancer. We have not integrated spring cloud and eureka services to perform load balancing and invoke external service calls.

Does it make sense to replace RestTemplate with feign-client only for not writing unit test cases?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this is related to unit tests, but you can replace `RestTemplate` with Spring Cloud OpenFeign for a leaner, more readable API. It may also handle client-side load-balancing for you under the hood. However, you might wish to wait till Spring 6 release and switch to using the new [Spring interface client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0-M4/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-http-interface-client) instead.

Comment: Will feign client do client-side load balancing if we are using AWS API Gateway instead of Spring Cloud Gateway?

Comment: The client-side load-balancing will work for a client that can pick instances from any Service Discovery, like Eureka or Consul or even in properties via SimpleServiceDiscoveryClient, so if you want to use it to get a proper Gateway instance, you can. I don;t see how you would use it within the Gateway itself if it's not one that has the integration, like SC Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

- We can use feign client without using the eureka server and config client. Feign client sits on top of the rest template.
- So for better intercommunication between two microservices feign client works fine.
- All you need to do is to supply additional parameter for url to the feign client @FeignClient along with name param
- The port needs to be a fixed port and cannot be randomized provided by spring boot. So user server port

> @FeignClient(name = "user-profile-service",
> url="${client.user-profile-service.baseurl}")

application.yml

```
client:
  skill-service:
    baseurl: http://localhost:3202
```